# Suppress synthetic mousemove DOM events on touch

Tags: javascript, dom, mouseevent, touchscreen

When listening to 'mousemove' events in Chrome on destkop, there is a synthetic event injected for any tapping on a touch screen, when the pointer is moving to that location.
This synthetic event is even injected to 'pointermove', and has event.type=='mouse' there. So it can't be filtered from real mouse events.

If so, how to listen on non-button press mouse movements while ignoring touch completely?